# Cookie created via jQuery ajax is then not recognized by the typical Asp.Net FormsAuthentication

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

This is a bit old school (web forms). My Asp.Net site uses FormsAuthentication for security with the typical settings for forms authentication in `web.config`. This works well. User logs in and is authenticated via back-end logic in business layer. So, now I have created a "back door" login technique using a simple form that posts user/pass via jquery ajax to the exact same back end logic code.

In both login scenarios, cookies are created, and in fact, comparing the two shows them to be identical. But, my problem: I log in via the jquery ajax, then when I go to my forms authentication protected page, I am redirected to the "log in page" as defined in web.config. If I reverse the situation and log in via the formsauthentication WebForm, then I AM successfully recognized as "logged in" at the jQuery ajax form.

I've tried so many things I am now confused. Path, domain, HttpOnly, Secure, etc.

I don't have code to show, but can if needed. I'm hoping this problem description might just ring a bell in someone's head.

Comment: Have you compared which cookies exist, and what their details are, for differences between the two approaches?

Comment: Compare the cookies, no the data on them, but the "owner" domine and the expiration of the cookies ...

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL the domain and all that *is* data on them.

Comment: Thank you for prompt replies. Appreciated. I have compared the cookies in the past, but I am revisiting that now. I will return with information. Thanks.

Comment: @Taplar, sorry I meant to say not only the data being stored by the app but also the data that is added by the creation process.

Comment: Just want to add that my site is hosted in IIS. I'm creating the cookie in one application, and trying to read it from another. Both applications exist in the same IIS website with the same domain. path="/".  Thanks.